# writing out checkbox list to string array for json php

Tags: php

I want to be able to write is a string that is an array which is going to be stored in a jason string in a data base. My code iterates over the checkboxes but I want to be able todo is test if the $input name is "interests"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="dvd" />` <-- checkbox lists
```

the other thing which I can't get is to put quotes around each $value like e.g "dvd", "computers"

```
$interests = '[';
$count = 1;
$counter = count($_POST["interests"]);
foreach($_POST as $checkbox => $input) {
    if(is_array($input)) {
    // test here is input is "interests"    
        foreach($input as $index => $value) {   
            $interests .= /*quote here*/ $value /*quote here*/ .= ($count < $counter) ? ',' : '';
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
}
$interests .= ']';
echo $interests;
```

interests is suppose to write out ["dvd", "computers", "hard drives"]
but it only writes out [dvd, computers, hard drives]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST["interests"] = array("dvd", "computers", "hard drives");
$interests = '["' . implode('","', $_POST["interests"]) . '"]';
echo $interests;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KGtWp9)

Comment: Why would you assign `$_POST['interests']` a value in the code?

Comment: For demonstration purposes

Comment: @Jon i was following an example from stackoverflow thats all im just learning php

Comment: Ahh, ok. Had just wondered why not just make a new one.  But cheers for it achieving its purpose! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead of manually creating the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['interests']);
```

Outputs

> ["dvd","tv","radio"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$interests = '';
$count = 1;
$counter = count($_POST["interests"]);
foreach($_POST as $checkbox => $input) {
    if(is_array($input)) {
    // test here is input is "interests"    
        foreach($input as $index => $value) {   
            $interests .= $value .= ($count < $counter) ? ',' : '';
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
}
$interests = json_encode($interests);
echo $interests;
```